# Automatic `log.info` completion in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

I am using Java and I log things like:

```
log.info("createArticle userId={} articleId={} title={} content={}", userId, articleId, title, content);
```

As you can see, when inputting this line into my IDE, I have to manually write down those characters like `"userId={} "`. Ideally, I hope I can simply type the `userId`, and Intellij IDEA will automatically help me fill out both `"userId={} "` (in the format string) and `, userId` (in the arguments list).

Question: How can I do that in IntelliJ IDEA? Or, is there any other ways to type such logging lines **faster**?

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to implement it with [Live Templates](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-live-templates.html) and `groovyScript` for one of the variables: take the second segment, split it by comma, concat in something like `part=${part}`:

`groovyScript("_1.split(',').collect { it.trim() + '={}' }.join(' ')", B)`

[image]

See [video](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/api/files/74-1016753?sign=MTYxNDIzMjUwMDAwMHwxMS00MzQ1N3w3NC0xMDE2NzUzfGtIZS1rR1VlSjdLY25FYjlnZm1BOEtX%0D%0ANVZkTWp0aEw0Ymd0d2dJcnVnRDgNCg%0D%0A&updated=1613928659192)

Comment: Er this does not work for a variable number of arguments...

Comment: How would a variable number of arguments work? Can you add a sample?

Comment: I mean I need to have a variable number of arguments. e.g. In one place I have `log.info("hello a={} b={}", a,b)` and in another place I write `log.info("goodbye x={} y={} z={}",x,y,z)`

Comment: It is not possible. Related request: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-216835

Comment: Aha sounds interesting!