# How to automatically create logging statements for Flutter in Intellij IIDEA?

Tags: flutter, dart, intellij-idea

I want to semi-automatically create logging statements for methods. For example:

```
Future<String> func(String a, int b, {String? x}) async {
Log.d(_TAG, 'func a=$a b=$b c=$c');
}
```

How can I do this using Intellij IDEA's live template?

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66270682/automatic-log-info-completion-in-intellij-idea), but we are talking about Dart (Flutter) instead of Java.

Answer (score 0):

Actually this can be done with different methods used compared with the [Java solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66270682/automatic-log-info-completion-in-intellij-idea). So I document it here in case anybody wants this :)

Create this live template:

[image]

Where the full script is: `groovyScript("_1.collect { ' ' + it + '=$' + it }.join('')", dartMethodParameters())`